# Why session is create new when android call second time web service in java

Tags: java, android, session, restful-url

This is a java web service method and we get a new session id when android user call second time. so how to solve it?
We are creating new sessionId when android client login and then they sent the same sessionId in the json string even then a new sessionId generate every time.

```
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

import com.bis.gauizz.utils.JsonUtil;

@Path("/Service")
public class WebService {

    @GET
    @Path("/Text")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getDataText() {
        System.out.println("in getDataText Method");
        return "in getDataText Method";

    }
    @GET
    @Path("/Json")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @HeaderParam("User-Agent")

    public String getDataJson(@Context UriInfo request,
            @Context HttpServletRequest req) throws InvalidKeyException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException,
            NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException,
            UnsupportedEncodingException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
            BadPaddingException {
        String returnJson = null;

        //User Agent
        String userAgent = req.getHeader("User-Agent").toString();
        System.out.println(userAgent);
        // Create sessionID
        HttpSession idSession = null;
        if(req.getSession(false) == null){
             idSession = req.getSession();
             if(idSession.isNew())
                {
                    System.out.println("New SessionId");

                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Old SessionId");
                    idSession = req.getSession(true);
                }
        }else{
        //To check SessionId is new Or not

        }
        if (idSession != null) {
            request.getQueryParameters().get("json");// most impotent
            JsonUtil jsonUtil = new JsonUtil();
            returnJson = jsonUtil.getJson(request.getQueryParameters()
                    .get("json"), idSession);

        } 
        return returnJson;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you use the same connection/HTTPClient from the client, resending cookies the server sent in reply to the first request. Otherwise a new session will be generated for every request.

Comment: Also, you probably shouldn't use sessions for your WS. They should be stateless, and you should authenticate every time. Otherwise it's going to be really difficult to automate testing.

Comment: As @MikkelLøkke said, it's easiest if you don't use HTTP-level sessions in WS/REST, but if you want to go that way, yes, it doesn't seem to have any issues.

Comment: what is the other option?

Comment: If you don't store a lot of state in the session, you could a) reauthenticate on each request or b) have a short-term token that represents the session; you *explicitly* pass it in the call, and it's part of the API.

Comment: "Perfect" is subjective, so it depends on your requirements. How are you going to scale it? Is it a high availability web service? If you have a stateless WS, (which is kind of a requirement if you're RESTful) scalability is easier. Throw in a load balancer, Job done! If you need distributed sessions or session replicating/syncing, things get somewhat more complicated. So "It depends". There are lots of things to consider. Also, it being a phone app, you might have network connectivity issues you need to deal with. This is easier if the WS is stateless. Happy coding.

Comment: in below I give client side android code. Please refer and give me suggestion what we need to do.